# Как сделать так, что бы элемент "Контакты" был самым правым?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
body background {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.header-up a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#header1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header2-up {
  background-color: #285023;
}
.header-up img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
#login {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.headerlogo {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}
#signin {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#logotype {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#tovari {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#vremya {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#vremyaraboti {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  float: right;
}
#telefon {
  font-size: 22px;
}
#zakazat {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#korzina {
  float: right;
  width: 109px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#korzinatext {
  float: right;
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#summa {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -18px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
.menu-right2 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right2 a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu-right {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
}
.menu1 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu1 a {
  color: #363636;
}
```

```html
<div class="header2-up">
  <div class="header-up">
    <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="sheterenka"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
    <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
    <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
    <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="headerlogo">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#" id="logotype">
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </a><span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/>от производителей</span>
  </div>
  <div id="vremya"><span id="vremyaraboti">ПН-ВС: 10:00 - 21:00</span>
    <br/><span id="telefon">+7 (495) 989-72-68</span>
  </div>
  <div id="zakazat">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/zakazat.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="korzina">
    <img src="images/korzina.png" /><a href="#" id="korzinatext">Корзина</a><span id="summa">35 560 р.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="header-down-backg">
  <div class="menu2">
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Продукты питания</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Мебель</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Керамика</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Одежда</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Обувь</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu1"><a href="#">Сувениры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right2"><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А "самым левым" значит перед "Продукты питания"? И ещё вопрос: вам хочется это сделать меняя разметку или стили?

Comment: Ошибся, самым правым

Comment: И тот и тот бы вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Меняем разметку (способ через float)

Дело в том, что `float: right;` "отрисовывает" элементы от последнего, поэтому чтобы элемент выводился последним, надо сделать чтобы он был первым с `float: right;":

```css
.header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
body background {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.header-up a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#header1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header2-up {
  background-color: #285023;
}
.header-up img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
#login {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.headerlogo {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}
#signin {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#logotype {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#tovari {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#vremya {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#vremyaraboti {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  float: right;
}
#telefon {
  font-size: 22px;
}
#zakazat {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#korzina {
  float: right;
  width: 109px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#korzinatext {
  float: right;
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#summa {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -18px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
.menu-right2 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right2 a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu-right {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
}
.menu1 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}1
.menu1 a {
  color: #363636;
}
```

```html
<div class="header2-up">
  <div class="header-up">
    <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="sheterenka"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
    <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
    <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
    <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="headerlogo">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#" id="logotype">
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </a><span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/>от производителей</span>
  </div>
  <div id="vremya"><span id="vremyaraboti">ПН-ВС: 10:00 - 21:00</span>
    <br/><span id="telefon">+7 (495) 989-72-68</span>
  </div>
  <div id="zakazat">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/zakazat.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="korzina">
    <img src="images/korzina.png" /><a href="#" id="korzinatext">Корзина</a><span id="summa">35 560 р.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="header-down-backg">
  <div class="menu2">
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Продукты питания</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Мебель</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Керамика</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Одежда</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Обувь</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu1"><a href="#">Сувениры</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="menu-right2"><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Более гибкий способ (flexbox)

Можно сделать так, чтобы элементы можно было бы не менять местами в разметке.

Добавляем контейнеру `display: flex` и `margin-left: auto;` для того элемента, с которого начинается правое меню.

Тогда не надо будет инвертировать порядок элементов в разметке. При этом добавляется возможность менять порядок элементов с помощью свойства `order`.

Для работы flexbox не нужны `float`, поэтому они будут игнорироваться.

Для данного случая это можно сделать так:

```
.menu1 + .menu-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Но, возможно, это будет лучше добавить через класс, чем проверять элементы на их соседство.

Полный пример:

```css
.header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
body background {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.header-up a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#header1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header2-up {
  background-color: #285023;
}
.header-up img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
#login {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.headerlogo {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}
#signin {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
#logotype {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#tovari {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#vremya {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#vremyaraboti {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  float: right;
}
#telefon {
  font-size: 22px;
}
#zakazat {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#korzina {
  float: right;
  width: 109px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#korzinatext {
  float: right;
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#summa {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -18px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
.menu-right2 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right2 a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu-right {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfcece;
  margin: 13px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu-right a {
  color: #363636;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-right a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 13px 13px 13px 0;
}
.menu1 a:hover {
  color: #a0821e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu1 a {
  color: #363636;
}

.menu2 {
  display: flex;
}

.menu1 + .menu-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header2-up">
  <div class="header-up">
    <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="sheterenka"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
    <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"></img><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
    <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
    <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="headerlogo">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#" id="logotype">
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </a><span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/>от производителей</span>
  </div>
  <div id="vremya"><span id="vremyaraboti">ПН-ВС: 10:00 - 21:00</span>
    <br/><span id="telefon">+7 (495) 989-72-68</span>
  </div>
  <div id="zakazat">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/zakazat.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="korzina">
    <img src="images/korzina.png" /><a href="#" id="korzinatext">Корзина</a><span id="summa">35 560 р.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="header-down-backg">
  <div class="menu2">
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Продукты питания</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Мебель</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Керамика</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Одежда</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="#">Обувь</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu1"><a href="#">Сувениры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right2"><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```